# Align text within align

Tags: align

I'm trying to align the text inside the following code - and remove the numbering on the text lines - but it has an odd slanted appearance and also the text lines are numbered. I've tried \nonumber but it doesn't work.

```
The reflected wave can be written in the form
\begin{equation}\label{b_at_x3_0_ricatti_bc_2}
\hat b_0(\omega,0) = \mathcal{\hat R}(\omega) \hat f (\omega),
\end{equation}
where, from the second equation in (\ref{matching_at_0_homog}) we have
\begin{eqnarray}\label{local_reflection_coeff_ricatti_3}
\mathcal{\hat R}(\omega) &=& \frac{T_0 \hat b(\omega,0)}{\hat f(\omega)} + R_0 \nonumber\\
\text{and then using equation (\ref{b_at_x3_0_ricatti_bc_1}) we have} \\ 
&=& \frac{\hat{R}(\omega,0)(\overbrace{T_0^2+R_0^2}^{=1})+R_0}{1+R_0 \hat{R}(\omega,0)} \nonumber \\
\text{and now using (\ref{R1T1_homog}) we have}  \\
&=&  \frac{\hat{R}(\omega,0)+R_0}{1+R_0 \hat{R}(\omega,0)},
\end{eqnarray}
```

How can I do both here? Help much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\intertext` to add text lines inside of `align`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

The reflected wave can be written in the form
\begin{equation}\label{b_at_x3_0_ricatti_bc_2}
\hat b_0(\omega,0) = \hat{\mathcal{R}}(\omega) \hat f(\omega),
\end{equation}
%
where, from the second equation in \eqref{matching_at_0_homog} we have
\begin{align}\label{local_reflection_coeff_ricatti_3}
\hat{\mathcal{R}}(\omega) &= \frac{T_0 \hat b(\omega,0)}{\hat f(\omega)} + R_0 
\intertext{and then using equation \eqref{b_at_x3_0_ricatti_bc_1} we have} 
\hat{\mathcal{R}}(\omega) &= \frac{\hat{R}(\omega,0)(\overbrace{T_0^2+R_0^2}^{=1})+R_0}{1+R_0 \hat{R}(\omega,0)} 
\intertext{and now using \eqref{R1T1_homog} we have} 
\hat{\mathcal{R}}(\omega) &= \frac{\hat{R}(\omega,0)+R_0}{1+R_0 \hat{R}(\omega,0)},
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1, though personally I'd favour `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Problem solved.

Comment: I (and the AMS) recommend `\eqref{<label>}` rather than `(\ref{<label>})`

Comment: Yes, sure, I updated my answer.